# Every locally free sheaf is Cohen-Macaulay on complex variety with at canonical singualities?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

Suppose $X$ is a normal complex space with at most singularities, can we say any locally free sheaf on it is Cohen-Macauly?
Recall that a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over  $X$ is called (maximal) Cohen-Macaulay if $depth_{\mathcal{O}_x}(\mathcal{F}_x) = \dim\mathcal{O}_x$ for any $x\in X$, where $\mathcal{O}_x$ is the local ring of $X$ at $x$.

How badly the singularities can the complex space $X$ possess to remain the above property?

Thanks!

Comment: Please confer the following MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69436/how-to-construct-log-canonical-or-calabi-yau-non-cohen-macaulay-singularitie

Comment: This holds if and only if $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't paid attention to your title. If $X$ has canonical singularities, it is Cohen-Macaulay by Elkik's theorem.

Comment: There is also a variant of canonical in the non-Q-Gorenstein case due to de Fernex-Hacon which doesn't imply Cohen-Macaulay if I recall correctly.